# Error: deadline-exceeded when working with firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have written a small contact form, that calls a firebase cloud function to store the request to cloud firestore. Everything works fine, except that after 60seconds the website throws the following error:

`Error: deadline-exceeded`

I used this reference:https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/7d514fb4700d3a1681c47bf3e0ff0fa3d7c91910/functions/functions/index.js

This is my cloud function:

```
exports.newRequest = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("requests")
    .add(data)
    .then(ref => {
        console.log(`New request written. ${ref}`)
        return ref.id
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", error.message, error)
    })
})
```

This is the function call:

```
const functions = firebase.functions()
    const addMessage = functions.httpsCallable(`newRequest`)
    addMessage({
      name: name,
      contact: contact,
      message: message,
      timestamp: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(`Cloud function called successfully. Ref: ${result.data}`)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Getting the Error details.
        var code = error.code
        var message = error.message
        var details = error.details
        console.log(code, message, details)
      })
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is the cloud function log:

```
7:19:33.751 PM newRequest Function execution started
7:19:33.751 PM newRequest Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
7:19:33.755 PM newRequest Function execution took 5 ms, finished with status code: 204
7:19:33.896 PM newRequest Function execution started
7:19:33.896 PM newRequest Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
7:19:34.744 PM newRequest New request written. [object Object]
7:19:34.746 PM newRequest Function execution took 851 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

My setup in detail:

- I got a gatsby page, where I init firebase.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
const firebaseConfig = {}
useEffect(() => {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    } else {
      console.log(firebase.apps)
    }
  })
```

- I got a contact form react component with the following handleSubmit method.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/functions"

const handleSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault()
    const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable(`newRequest`)
    addMessage({
      name: name,
      contact: contact,
      message: message,
      timestamp: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(`Cloud function called successfully. Ref: ${result.data}`)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Getting the Error details.
        var code = error.code
        var message = error.message
        var details = error.details
        console.log(code, message, details)
      })
    resetName()
    resetContact()
    resetMessage()
  }
```

This is what the chrome dev tools say:

```
Exception: Error: deadline-exceeded at new HttpsErrorImpl (http://localhost:8000/commons.js:4409:28) at http://localhost:8000/commons.js:4715:20
code: "deadline-exceeded"
details: undefined
message: "deadline-exceeded"
stack: "Error: deadline-exceeded↵    at new HttpsErrorImpl (http://localhost:8000/commons.js:4409:28)↵    at http://localhost:8000/commons.js:4715:20"
__proto__: Error
```

And this is the promise creator:

```
/**
 * Returns a Promise that will be rejected after the given duration.
 * The error will be of type HttpsErrorImpl.
 *
 * @param millis Number of milliseconds to wait before rejecting.
 */
function failAfter(millis) {
    return new Promise(function (_, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject(new HttpsErrorImpl('deadline-exceeded', 'deadline-exceeded'));
        }, millis);
    });
}
```

I'm experiencing this problem since several days now and I don't know where it is comming from :(

Comment: The error message is suggesting that your call to the function timed out on the client.  You're going to have to give more information about what you're observing on both the function and client side.

Comment: Hey Doug! Thank you very much for your reply. Love you firebase videos on youtube. :D I edited my question. Maybe this will help.

Comment: I don't understand what `failAfter` is or how you're using it.

Comment: `failAfter` is a method from the firebase-functions package I installed (@firebase/functions/dist/index.cjs.js, ). I don't use is it. But is seems to produce the Promise.
I use this firebase version:
`"firebase": "^6.3.1",
"firebase-admin": "^8.3.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"`

Comment: Yeah, that's what's causing your timeout.  Something is stuck with the network connection, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: Well, I just restarted Chrome and the error is gone. I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

3 years later! I got this error also on a long running (e.g. 2 mins) firebase function, also using HttpsCallable like the OP

> FirebaseError functions/deadline-exceeded

I fixed it by making 2 changes:

(1) increase the firebase function timeout on the server as follows:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 540
}).https.onCall(async (data: any) => {
  return await myFunction(data)
})
```

OR

alternatively you can manually set the firebase function timeout via the GCP console at https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list?project=YOUR-PROJECT

click the function name and click edit and you can increase the timeout there

(2) set the HttpsCallableOptions timeout option:

```
const functions: Functions = getFunctions()
const options: HttpsCallableOptions = { timeout: 530 * 1000 } // slightly less than the 540 seconds BE timeout
const callable: HttpsCallable = httpsCallable(functions, 'flowPlayerExists', options)
const promise: Promise<HttpsCallableResult> = callable({ id })
```

I had to make BOTH these changes to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Is it "useEffect" from React Hooks ?

If yes, your firebase init (in useEffect) is done every render.

If you want that useEffect apply only once (like componentDidMount) you should pass an empty array in second param.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    } else {
      console.log(firebase.apps)
    }
}, []);
```